# Error on WordPress attachement page in backend

Tags: php, wordpress, imagick

I get an error on every attachement page in the WordPress backend.
Direct under the title of the attachement it shows the following error:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(23) "WP_Image_Editor_Imagick" [1]=> string(18) "WP_Image_Editor_GD" }
```

Here's a screen of the error: [image]

I've checked my PHP info and it says, that imagick is active in versio 3.4.3.
See here: [image]

I'm using PHP 7.1.3 (PHP-FPM) on a nginx server.

Any ideas how I could remove the error?

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of the error ?

Comment: done, I added a screenshot

Comment: That does not look like an error to me, did you modify a code on wordpress ? Or are you using a custom plugin ? Because it looks like `var_dump()` is written on this page.
And does the media upload works l?

Comment: Hmm, I've not changed any code of WordPress. Media upload works

Comment: solved it.... it was a `var_dump()` in the functions.php. Thanks for your hint. If you post it as answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a var_dump in my funtions.php

Answer (score 1):

Try following things to set default image editor:

```
add_filter( 'wp_image_editors', 'change_graphic_lib' );


function change_graphic_lib() {
return array( 'WP_Image_Editor_GD', 'WP_Image_Editor_Imagick' );
}
```

It will solve your issue.

Comment: Please make sure that your Image library version is compatible with your php version

Comment: I've tried several php version and always getting the error